# Docker DNS setup

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dns, ubuntu-18.04

I have a setup with a local DNS hosted in docker. For various reasons, I need to be able to use this DNS in other docker containers. Case in point:

I have a container, **sso** that issues JWT tokens to users. This token refers to its external name **sso.example.com** and client services must authenticate this.

Now, sso.example.com is both available externally (by Google DNS et al), but also registered on my local DNS.

However, I simply cannot get my other containers to resolve names in the following order:

- Docker DNS (127.0.0.11)
- DNS in docker (172.17.42.x, and 192.168.1.42 on host)
- External DNS (1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8)

What is the proper way to achieve being able to resolve both LAN DNS and Docker DNS. I'm on Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

Your client will only ask a single DNS server to resolve a name. If the name is not found by the server, the client will be unable to resolve the name.
Having multiple nameservers in /etc/resolv.conf only helps if a request to one of them results in a timeout, the next is used.

I suggest you configure the Docker DNS server on all clients. This DNS server should answer and cache or forward requests to secondary servers accordingly. But I am not an expert on bind/DNS server configuration.

Maybe this can help, although it is for an older version of Ubuntu: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-caching-or-forwarding-dns-server-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup the containers to use your local DNS, and your local DNS should have forwarders to attend domains that are not define in your zone file. Thats what we use in our company, and a better way to determine what DNS response should be delivered you can use "views", a view lets you resolve a IP adress based in your source IP address.

**named.conf.options**

```
allow-recursion { ACL1; ACL2; };
    forwarders {
        //Google
        8.8.8.8;
        8.8.4.4;
};
```

**named.conf.local**

```
view "v1" {
    match-clients { ACL1; };
    zone "example.net" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/acl1.example.net";
        allow-transfer { none; };
    };
};

view "v2" {
    match-clients { ACL2; };
    zone "example.net" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/acl2.example.net";
        allow-transfer { none; };
    };
};
```

Note that you cant use the same file for 2 views